# Gitlab CI/CD switching job to manual mode dynamically

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there any way to switch a job to **manual** mode (and vice-versa) dynamically?

So, instead of having `when: manual` in `gitlab-ci.yml` file, it would be switched to manual (or the opposite) according to any dynamic checking.

Example: Lacking of configuration from environment variables that prevents it to run, but the user could run it later if they set the variables at the launch time.

**Just playing with the current syntax, it could be like:**

```yaml
myjob:
   stage: deploy
   environment: proj-shared-env-qa
   script:
      - echo "Deploying $my_var..."
   when: manual && [[ ! $my_var ]] # Using shell syntax just as an example of the condition
```

**Instead of failing:**

```yaml
myjob:
   stage: deploy
   environment: proj-shared-env-qa
   script:
      - [[ ! $my_var ]] && echo "my_var is undefined" && exit 1
      - echo "Deploying $my_var..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `rules` to set a condition based on a variable you set in the `script` of the job.

```
myjob:
   stage: deploy
   environment: proj-shared-env-qa
   script:
      - export my_var
   rules:
     - if: $my_var
       when: manual
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of rules if with below example

```
myjob:
   stage: deploy
   environment: proj-shared-env-qa
   script:
      - echo "Deploying $my_var..."
   rules:
     - if: $my_var
       when: on_success
     - if: !$my_var
       when: manual
```

So if var is set then it will automatically run. if it is not set then it'll become a manual process

Ref: [Gitlab Rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif)